# electron-compile: Can’t use Stylus

Tags: electron, stylus

I’m working on an app with `electron-compile` and I'm having a strange issue where I can’t compile my files

I know the problem isn’t with my styles because they still won’t load when I change them to just

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The styles aren’t loading because apparently the styles couldn’t compile. When I open the stylesheet in question in the DevTools, I get this:

```
Failed to compile /path/to/src/renderer/styles/styles.styl: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ''
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ''
```

I've checked multiple times and the path is correct.

Another reason I know that the problem is with `electron-compile` or maybe just `electron` is because if I change the file and it re-compiles, the styles load, but if I reload the page they disappear.

Comment: Have you tried using electron-forge? Whatever that includes seems to work for Stylus, at least mostly. I have issues using `@import` and `@require`. Other than that though.

Comment: @GeoffJohnson I am using `electron-forge`. I had some issues with `@import` and `@require` as well :)

Comment: I have the same issue @Hum4n01d said :(

Comment: If you have solved it please share it

Comment: @ShankarUs I'm using styled-components now

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me, when my @import paths start from app directory and not relative to actual styl file.

Like this:

`@import 'styl/global/_common';`